# how to upgrade Unit tests from Grails 3.1.8 to 3.3.0?

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I upgrade from Grails 3.1.8 to Grails 3.3.0 ..
there is some changes with testing ..
I am trying to use testing-support library provided with Grails 3.3.0.
I have an error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at EmailTemplateControllerSpec.groovy:13
```

with this unit test with the controller ..

```
class EmailTemplateControllerSpec extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest<EmailTemplateController> {

void "test index, ok"() {
    given:
    controller.emailTemplateService = Stub(EmailTemplateService) {
        list(_, _) >> {
            new EmailTemplateService.EmailTemplateResult(success: true, data: ["a", "b"])
        }
    }
    when:
    controller.index()
    then:
    view == "/emailTemplate/index"
    model.templates.size() == 2
    model.errorMessage == null
}
```

Comment: You're probably going to need to give us both the controller method (index), so we can see what model is being passed to render, and what the error *actually* is... what method is missing?

Comment: this test is working with grails 3.1.8

Comment: only . when i wanted to work with grails 3.3 it stopped working

Comment: What is line 13? There's not enough to go on here.  Also you can use the "old" mixin testing still, just not included by default in 3.3

Comment: Impossible to tell you the issue without more information like 2 others previously have said